# Is there is any way to get public post of facebook by location ?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Hello i am new to Facebook graph api  and looking for getting all the users public post in facebook by location using Facebook graph api .There are some existing apps like Geofeedia,COEverywhere, TrackinU which can get public posts of social networking sites by location . Is there is any way to get public post of an area in Facebook ?

Comment: You mean for a specific user, or just posts by all users? You can not get “all” public posts any more from Graph API. Only FB partners with access to the Public Feed API can access public posts for unspecified users. (And no, there is no way for you to apply. You could only work with one of those partners, which will likely cost you.)

Comment: Thanks for the  reply ,but i think Public Feed API is not available anymore (since API V 2.0). You can't  request for permission to access it. If its still available .please help me how to become FB  partner and can get permission to get public post .

Comment: It is available in the same way as it was from the beginning – to partners only. And that you can not apply to become one, I said already. If you want to use that kind of data, you need to work with one of the partners that have access. (A list is somewhere in the documentation.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Public Feed API
The Public Feed API displays a real-time feed of public posts for a specific word. Only public posts (from Pages and Profiles of those with ‘Follow’ turned on) are available with this API.

Keyword Insights API
The Keyword Insights API aggregates the total number of posts that mention a specific term in a given time frame. It can also display anonymous,
aggregated results based on gender, age and location.

Our current list of partners includes: Buzzfeed, CNN, NBC’s Today Show, BSkyB, Slate. and Mass Relevance.

These two tools are currently only available for a small group of trusted media partners.