# How to submit request to facebook for approval for Public feed API?

Tags: facebook-public-feed-api

Public Feed API The Public Feed API displays a real-time feed of public posts for a specific word. Only public posts (from Pages and Profiles of those with ‘Follow’ turned on) are available with this API.

if anybody has any idea please help

Comment: Do you have any relevant code so far? Have you checked their API? See also: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: well i am new to facebook api and want to get all the public post by location someone told me that it can be done using public feed api of facebook .http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33232208/is-there-is-any-way-to-get-public-post-of-facebook-by-location?noredirect=1#comment54286855_33232208

Comment: This is not the right place to ask about Facebook API. You need to ask strictly programming questions (most of the cases about your existing code) or ask very clear question, and in which programming language. If you need more information about FB API, try: https://developers.facebook.com/

Comment: thnks for your your reply and  time buddy.